# Separate table sum join

Tags: sql, database, join, sum, union

I have following tables with some ddata as described below

Table A

```
------------------------------------ 
      date    |  cnt  |  click  |  point 
------------------------------------ 
2014-07-01 |  3    |    5    |    10 

2014-07-03 |  5    |    15    |    20 

2014-07-05 |  1    |    2    |    3
```

Table B

```
------------------------------------ 
      date    |  cnt  |  click  |  point 
------------------------------------ 
2014-07-02 |  3    |    5    |    10 

2014-07-03 |  3    |    5    |    20 

2014-07-06 |  1    |    2    |    3
```

Table C

```
------------------------------------ 
      date    |  cnt  |  click  |  point 
------------------------------------ 
2014-07-01 |  3    |    5    |    10 

2014-07-02 |  2    |    3    |    30 

2014-07-05 |  1    |    2    |    3
```

result

```
------------------------------------ 
      date    |  cnt  |  click  |  point 
------------------------------------ 
2014-07-01 |  6    |    10    |    20 

2014-07-02 |  5    |    8      |    40 

2014-07-03 |  8    |    20    |    40 

2014-07-05 |  2    |    4    |    6 

2014-07-06 |  1    |    2    |    3
```

Above Join result but not union all.
Any suggestion please?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do not use union all query optimization to obtain the advice to another.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

You could `union all` all three tables and sum the results:

```
SELECT   `date`, SUM(cnt), SUM(click), SUM(point)
FROM     (SELECT `date`, cnt, click, point FROM a
          UNION ALL
          SELECT `date`, cnt, click, point FROM b
          UNION ALL
          SELECT `date`, cnt, click, point FROM c) t
GROUP BY `date`
```